# How to increase my codeigniter application performance?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, codeigniter-3

I have an codeigniter application which constantly gets data from the web-socket connected using node Js

So the node will get the data from the web-socket and pass it the codeigniter application function and this function will insert the data first in the MySQL database and then redirect to another function this function will process the inserted data and then redirect to another function and this function will send the processed data to the API

So roughly my controller will look like this

```
function data_from_node(){
  // code to insert the data from node into database
  redirect('my_controller/data_process');
}

function data_process(){
  // code to process the inserted data
  redirect('my_controller/send_to_api');
}

function send_to_api(){
  // code to send the processed data to the API
}
```

For one process there will be almost 200 data will be coming from the node and the whole process should complete with 5 -6 mins, This is working perfectly when there is less data in the MySQL database,when the data in the database is increasing the application is getting slower and it takes around 10 mins to complete a single process

Can anyone help me with a solution to increase a performance of my application, The process should take only 5-6 mins even though there are millions of records in the database.

Comment: Is there a reason you a using a redirect instead of a direct method call? You should also consider inserting data in bulk if possible. The DB_query_builder has a suitable function for this: insert_batch.

Comment: As of now it is inserting 200 data one by one taking one by one data and processing 
and you are suggesting to insert the data 200 at once and process the data after am I correct?

Comment: Yes - currently you are initializing Codeigner, your database and all your code three times for every piece of data (since redirect performs a http redirect). If you insert all data at once you only have to do this three times (assuming your can process and send the data in bulk).

Comment: Ok understood, Thanks for this suggestion